# XamGrid doesn't allow to select empty text

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, infragistics, wpf-4.0, xamgrid

I am using Infrgistics XamGrid [InfragisticsWPF4.Controls.Grids.XamGrid.v12.1.dll (12.1.20121.1010)]. I have a situation where user cannot filter to select only empty text. Filter works fine in cases where non empty text are selected, but any combination including empty text excludes empty rows. E.g. In sample provided below, if user tries to select "PTL_D_IMA" and empty text, result of filter turns out to be only one row having "PTL_D_IMA" whereas the other other two rows with empty text do not appear.

```
<ig:XamGrid x:Name="myGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TestDataItems}}">
 <ig:XamGrid.FilteringSettings>
 <ig:FilteringSettings AllowFiltering="FilterMenu"FilteringScope="ColumnLayout" />
 </ig:XamGrid.FilteringSettings>
 </ig:XamGrid>

 public class TestDataItems  
{ 
private string name; 
public string Name 
{
 get { return name; }  
 set { name = value; } 
} 
}

public class TestData : ObservableCollection<TestDataItems> 
{ 
 public TestData() 
 { 
  Add(new TestDataItems { Name = "PTL_D_IMA"}); 
  Add(new TestDataItems { Name = "PTL_D_PCHCYL"}); 
  Add(new TestDataItems { Name = "PTL_D_ICN"}); 
  Add(new TestDataItems { Name = "PTL_D_PRFI"}); 
  Add(new TestDataItems { Name = "PTL_D_IPH"}); 
  Add(new TestDataItems { Name = ""}); 
  Add(newTestDataItems { Name = string.Empty }); 
  Add(newTestDataItems { Name = "PTL_D_PTCYL"}); 
  Add(new TestDataItems { Name = "PCGM"}); 
  Add(new TestDataItems { Name = "COD_SUS"}); 
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved in a service release of NetAdvantage for WPF.  As long as you have your product key registered you can download the service release from the [My Keys and Downloads](https://www.infragistics.com/my-account/keys-and-downloads/) page.  If you are using a trial and want to get the service release, you can install it by running the platform installer and make sure the option to check for updates or install the service release is checked.